Troubleshooting Dell Keyboard Issue
I was able to deterimine that my keyboard is attached to the system by running lsusb command and I get the following:
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard

But the keyboard isnt typing any alphabets/numerics etc. So I looked for if its registering any events and I ran evtest and it gave following relevant events:
/dev/input/event21: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
/dev/input/event22: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard System Control
/dev/input/event23: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard Consumer Control

I was able to check for event23 as the controls like music play, search and sleep were being registered from the keyboard but event21 where listening for different keypresses such as alphabets and numerics were not registering any events.
Does that mean my keyboard is half faulty?

"But the keyboad isnt working" insufficient data on which to offer any possible solutions... [edit] your question with more detail

@graham thanks for the suggestion. I updated it.

how about providing distro/version, keyboard layout set and language in Settings Input Sources > Keyboard Did you try another keyboard? USB PS2, dis you try it with a Live USB - so many aspects missing here.
